# The screen becomes black when I launch a fragment from a tabbed activity in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, tabs

I'm doing an application where there's a user who can order from stores and so on. It's a little big application because there's also a part where a manager can manage the users and stores.

Here's the problem: in the manager part i have a tabbed activity which launches correctly and everything is OK, but when I try to launch the another tab with a fragment (if i don't add any fragment it works fine) the screen becomes black and crashes without any error or warning.

My code:

PageViewModel class:

```
public class PageViewModel extends ViewModel {

private MutableLiveData<Integer> mIndex = new MutableLiveData<>();
private LiveData<String> mText = Transformations.map(mIndex, new Function<Integer, String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(Integer input) {
        return "Hello world from section: " + input;
    }
});

public void setIndex(int index) {
    mIndex.setValue(index);
}

public LiveData<String> getText() {
    return mText;
}
```

}

Placeholder Class:

```
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

private PageViewModel pageViewModel;

public static Fragment newInstance(int index) {
    Fragment fragment=null;
    switch (index){
        case 1: fragment= new StoreManagement();
            break;
        case 2: fragment= new User_StoreManagement();
            break;
    }
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pageViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(PageViewModel.class);
    int index = 1;
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        index = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
    }
    pageViewModel.setIndex(index);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(
        @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user__store_management, container, false);
    final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
    pageViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
            //textView.setText(s);
        }
    });
    return root;
}
```

}

SeccionPageAdapter class:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

@StringRes
private static final int[] TAB_TITLES = new int[]{R.string.tab_stores, R.string.tab_orders};
private final Context mContext;

public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
    // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
    return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mContext.getResources().getString(TAB_TITLES[position]);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Show 2 total pages.
    return 2;
}
```

}

TabbedActivity:

```
public class UserTabbedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_tabbed);
    SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
    ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabs = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

The layout:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".userViews.UserTabbedActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AsociacionIsaYCristian.AppBarOverlay">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
            android:padding="@dimen/appbar_padding"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Sorry if the formatting is incorrect and for my English. Thanks for helping me.

Comment: I suggest migrating to viewpager2
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/vp2-migration

Comment: Try this:
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)